# Temporary storage for array in Meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

I am using `ReactiveDict` to change the state and styling of one or more templates.  I would like to save the `id` of each selected template into an array that I can then use in a method.  Before I trigger this event, user needs to be able to add and remove any `id` from the array until determined final.

How can I create an array with all the `id`s whose `template.instance().state` is set to `isSelectedId`?

I thought I could use `array.push()` on each click and save to a Session variable, but the Session variable does not change.  I also then don't have a way to remove the specific `id` if unselected.  I also considered saving to a collection, but I only want temporary storage.

EDITED CODE TO INCLUDE PART OF ANSWER USING LOCAL COLLECTION

```
<template name="App">
    <div id="app-inner">
        {{#each companies}}
            {{>Company}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="Company">
    <div class="company {{isSelected}}">
        <a>Company: {{companyName}}</a>
    </div>
</template>

Template.App.helpers({
    companies: function() {
        return Companies.find({});
    }
});

Template.Company.events({
    'click .company': function(e) {
        var state = Template.instance().state.get('isSelectedId');
        var id = this._id;
        var count = localSelections.find().count();
        if(count === 0) {
            var localId = localSelections.insert({});
        }
        console.log("Local ID: ", localId);
        switch (state) {
            case null:
                Template.instance().state.set('isSelectedId', this._id);
                localSelections.update({_id:localId},{$push:{select:id}});
                break;
            case id:
                Template.instance().state.set('isSelectedId', null);
                localSelections.update({_id:localId},{$pull:{select:id}});
                break;
        }
    }
});

Template.Company.helpers({
    'isSelected': function() {
        return this._id === Template.instance().state.get('isSelectedId') ? 'is-selected' : '';
    }
});

Template.Company.onCreated(function() {
    this.state = new ReactiveDict;
    this.state.set('isSelectedId', null);
});

//client/collections
    localSelections = new Mongo.Collection(null);

Meteor.methods({
    valuationAdd: function(array) {
        check(array, Array);
        Valuations.insert({selections:array});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Temporary* client-side storage is easy to create in a [local (unmanaged) collection](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html)

myLocalCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);

Such a collection has all the normal features of a collection except:

- It never gets synchronized to the server
- You can update or delete multiple documents at a time with `{multi: true}`

I recently wrote an [article on TheMeteorChef](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-meteor-local-collections-to-support-browser-based-cryptography/) about how to use these.

Comment: Thanks Michel, as always, this should work great.  I revised my code above to show my progress.  One follow-up question though - I will need to save the ids in an array in one document.  The code above creates a document and adds the id for the first item clicked (`console.log(localId)` properly returns the id created).  But it can't read the `localId` for subsequent clicks.  Should I or can I create this document somewhere outside the event handler?

Comment: I *believe* you're trying to track the `_id`s of your `Company` documents. You could just `localSelections.insert({_id: this._id})` and create a 1:1 match with your `Company` documents.

Comment: Thanks, yes just tracking the `_id`s of `Company` documents.  I thought I would save a step by just saving into one local document, but I am able to use separate documents and then push each `id` into an array afterwards.  All works great.